# How can I change my URL before loading my view?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter webpage containing (i) a list of items and (ii) a form to add a new item or edit the details of a selected item.

To select an item for editing, I have an "edit" anchor tag with a hyperlink ending with `?id=nnn`. This results in a GET request that populates the detail fields of my selected item and redisplays the list. My URL now contains `site_address/index.php/country?id=151`.

When I submit my changes the list is updated correctly but my URL remains unchanged. What do I need to do in my controller to remove "?id=151 after my update was successful?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of everything you are doing, so I'll just answer directly:

in your controller, after you update, you can:

```
redirect('site_address/index.php/country');
```

Does that fit what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Through php there's no way to change URL after request expect redirecting

```
redirect('controller/method');
```

and you can success message using session flash message after redirecting, if that what makes you want to reload the view

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ahmed. I solved the problem by redirecting just after I verified that my update was successful. Francois